# The symbol $n$? Natural numbers?

Tags: number-theory, notation

This might seem like a very basic question, but it keeps bugging me.

Does the symbol $n$ mean the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ shortened to $n$ to ease writing?

Or is it rather the positive and negative quantities (known as integers ($\mathbb{Z}$)

Or real numbers $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What do you want it to mean?  It's your Question.  Many authors use $n$ to denote a particular number, often an integer.  Sometimes a natural number.  But it's up to the author to define the meaning, which if you look carefully was probably done in the contexts you are asking about (without references).

Comment: Can you provide some context? What textbook are you reading?

Comment: It is everywhere in mathematical language, just wondered if n means natural numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\mathbb{N}$ is the natural numbers. But usually in the context of number theory when one writes $n$, one means a particular natural number. For example, $n$ could be $5$ or $12$ or $1$ or $1,234,453,564,234,134,179,200$. But they would usually *not* use it to denote any integer and certainly not a real number.

In any case, what the variable $n$ is being used for should always be stated somewhere in the text whenever it is used, so search for what they have declared it to represent.